# Modify a SELECT statement before it's executed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table that I need to prevent access to unless explicitly requested.
For the sake of the matter, let's say it's ProductId = 2.

What I need, is a way to prevent queries against the table to return ProductID 2 unless explicitly requested.
So if someone queries

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

I need a
`WHERE ProductId <> 2`
to be added to the query.

The only way I can think of dealing with this is by creating a view that does that, and have all queries go through the view. But that still leaves room for human error, which I'd like to avoid.

Any way of doing this?

Comment: You create the view, then restrict access to the table.

Comment: Problem is, that doesn't prevent ME from causing a human error, and forgetting I need to go though the view...

Comment: Its pretty hard to stop someone with admin access from accessing it. You might have more luck storing ProductID 2 in a separate table.

Comment: View & access control is standard solution. If you are afraid of human error and insist on using `MyTable`, then don't store data there. You can alternatively store data into separate table `MyTableWithSuperSecretDataOfProduct2`. Anyway you will have to restrict access to that table as well as to view unioning these two tables.

Comment: I am partly with Tomáš Záluský, here. But I think it should suffice to use good names. If you name that view `MyTable` and the table `Very_Dangerous_Table_Containg_Product2`, it becomes less likely to use the wrong one :-)

Comment: @Ethan1701 . . . There is no human error when using views.  Just don't allow any users to have direct query access to the table.  Have two views, one without "2" and one with "2".  Only qualified users can use the second one.

Comment: Maybe you seek [row level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your clarification, In SQL 2016+ you can implement Row-Level Security, however, it sounds like the simple solution is to create stored procedures with  ProductID as an input parameter and then use IF ... THEN logic to accomplish your goal.  I am providing a basic sample but you will have to build the appropriate level of complexity in your logic to accomplish your goal, e.g., perhaps you need to pass in more than one ProductID at a time, etc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetProductsFromMyTable   
@ProductID INT = NULL  
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF @ProductID <> 2
 BEGIN;
  SELECT * FROM MyTable
  WHERE ProductID <> 2
  AND (@ProductID IS NULL OR ProductID = @ProductID);  
 END;
IF @ProductID = 2
 BEGIN;
  SELECT * FROM MyTable
  WHERE ProductID = 2
  AND (@ProductID IS NULL OR ProductID = @ProductID);  
 END;
```

Comment: Thats not really an answer is it? Just asking for clarification and mentioning a potentially relevant idea. Best keep that sort of thing to comments.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2016. Front end is usually SSMS, but could also be SSRS, in both cases, most queries would be written by me, and I want to make sure I never accidentally provide my users with informatiln about ProductID 2 unless explicitly asked to. What I might do is look to upgrade, implement row-level security, and use seperate logins to provide users with data